# Tell my friends to which "comma club" they belong

Tags: code-golf

Inspired by Silicon Valley's "three-comma club" scenes, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIB5HEcZBs8), in this challenge you'll be telling ten people the "comma club" to which they each belong.

If you're unfamiliar with the term "comma club," let me explain: you're in the one-comma club if the money you have is in the inclusive range $1,000.00 to $999,999.99; you're in the two-comma club if it's in the range $1,000,000.00 to $999,999,999.99; these "clubs" repeat through the three-comma club, since no individual on Earth (AFAIK) owns more than one trillion U.S. dollars (Japanese Yen would be a different story very quickly). So, the number of commas your bank account has, according to the notation standards most common in the United States and Great Britain, denotes the comma club to which you belong. The same "comma" rules apply for negative numbers (although you wouldn't want to be in the negative comma club): negative amounts in the inclusive range [-0.01, -999.99] belong to the zero-comma club, amounts in the range [-1000.00, -999999.99] belong to the one-comma club, etc.

## The test cases

```
Friend    Amount
John      100000
Jamie     0.05
Kylie     1549001.10
Laura     999999999.99
Russ      986000000
Karla     1
Reid      99.99
Mark      999.99
Manson    1000.01
Lonnie    999999999999.00
Nelly     -123.45
```

The right answers:

```
John is in the 1-comma club.
Jamie is in the 0-comma club.
Kylie is in the 2-comma club.
Laura is in the 2-comma club.
Russ is in the 2-comma club.
Karla is in the 0-comma club.
Reid is in the 0-comma club.
Mark is in the 0-comma club.
Manson is in the 1-comma club.
Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.
Nelly is in the 0-comma club.
```

Whatever array setup you need to get a `friends` array and `amounts` array does not count towards your score. So for Python, the following code doesn't count:

```
f = ['John', 'Jamie', 'Kylie', 'Laura', 'Russ', 'Karla', 'Reid', 'Mark', 'Manson', 'Lonnie']
a = ['100000', '0.05', '1549001.10', '999999999.99', '986000000', '1', '99.99', '999.99', '1000.01', '999999999999.00']
```

#### Edit: Please see the revised test cases

I removed the actual string commas from the test cases to make things a bit more difficult, as opposed to just counting commas.

Comment: I don't think you've made the output format very clear. Is something like `"Name number,Name number,..."` acceptable?

Comment: Are the entries in f guaranteed to be positive, or would `-$1,234.56` also be in the 1-comma club?

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes, good point. Technically that's a comma club. The entries are not guaranteed to be positive. You're basically counting the number of commas.

Comment: Wait, will we not have commas in the input?

Comment: Please see the revised test cases. When I initially thought of this challenge, I wanted to leave out actual commas in the dollar strings above. That change is now reflected.

Comment: May we take the numbers in any format desired, e.g. strings?

Comment: @R.Kap yes, that's fine.

Comment: Can we assume that there will no duplicate names?

Comment: @Titus yes, that's fine.

Comment: @not_a_robot Could you address Fry's comment? Is it sufficient to output pairs of name and number in any format?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman No, the output needs to be in the format `"<name> is in the <number of commas>-club."`

Comment: The question, ignoring comments (which it's reasonable to assume that people will do when answering) still doesn't specify to which comma club anyone with less than $1000 belongs.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, it does. Check out the test cases: Reid has $99.99, and the correct output is `Reid is in the 0-comma club.`

Comment: Test cases are not spec. And even if they were, there's no test case covering the issue of large negatives raised by Jonathan Allan above.

Comment: Please edit the question to lay out in detail (not just in test cases) whether negative numbers with commas are part of a club or are always 0-comma club

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```
a=>a.map(([s,n])=>s+` is in the ${n.toFixed(n<0?3:4).length/3-2|0}-comma club.`)
```

Takes an array of [friend, amount] arrays and returns an array of "friend is in the n-comma club." strings. Works by adding extra trailing zeros so that the length is 6-8 for the 0-comma club, 9-11 for the 1-comma club, 12-15 for the 2-comma club etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/cau40vmk/1/

Comment: I don't think this works for negative numbers. For instance, it would put Nelly (-123.45) in the 1-comma club. I'd suggest the shorter `Math.log10(n*n)/6|0`.

Comment: @Arnauld Ah yes, I'd forgotten `|0` truncates to zero, so it gives the right answer for Jamie.

Answer (score 10):

## PostgreSQL, 61 bytes

```sql
SELECT f||' is in the '||div(log(@a),3)||'-comma club.'FROM p
```

`@x` is the absolute value of `x`, `log(x)` is base-10 logarithm and `div(y, x)` computes the integer quotient of y/x.

---

Setup:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE p AS
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('John', 100000),
    ('Jamie', 0.05),
    ('Kylie', 1549001.10),
    ('Laura', 999999999.99),
    ('Russ', 986000000),
    ('Karla', 1),
    ('Reid', 99.99),
    ('Mark', 999.99),
    ('Manson', 1000.01),
    ('Lonnie', 999999999999.00),
    ('Nelly', -123.45)
) AS p (f, a)
```

---

Output:

```
            ?column?            
--------------------------------
 John is in the 1-comma club.
 Jamie is in the 0-comma club.
 Kylie is in the 2-comma club.
 Laura is in the 2-comma club.
 Russ is in the 2-comma club.
 Karla is in the 0-comma club.
 Reid is in the 0-comma club.
 Mark is in the 0-comma club.
 Manson is in the 1-comma club.
 Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.
 Nelly is in the 0-comma club.
(11 rows)
```

Comment: It's nice to see a competitive SQL answer - well done!

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>34 32</s>  31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
AḞbȷL’⁶;“£ṙƬs⁾`¬ụṂ“¢<ỴȦ8£l»j)⁹żY
```

A dyadic link (function) which takes a list of bank balances as numbers (decimals / integers) and a list of names as strings and returns a list of strings.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/x4Y55SSe2@zxqmPmocZv1o4Y5hxY/3Dnz2JriR437Eg6tebh76cOdTSDhRTYPd285sczi0OKcQ7uzNB817jy65//h5ZH//0cbGoCAjoKBnoGpjoKhqYmlgYGhniFQxBIG9CwtgTIGMABkgyTBosiyegaGSJpAMiC1uoZGxnomQKN14YbF/o9W98rPyFPXUVD3SszNTAUxvCtzIAyfxNKiRBAjqLS4GCyTWJQDEUjNTAHRvolF2RA6rzgfbIpPfl4eRLcfKGggjPT0SvVYAA)** - the footer `çY`simply calls the function and joins the resulting list with line feeds so it has nice output when run as a full program.

#### How?

```
AḞbȷL’⁶;“£ṙƬs⁾`¬ụṂ“¢<ỴȦ8£l»j)⁹ż - Main link: bankBalances, names
                            )   - for each bankBalance:
A                               -   absolute value (treat negatives and positives the same)
 Ḟ                              -   floor (get rid of any pennies)
  bȷ                            -   convert to base 1000
    L                           -   length (number of digits in base 1000)
     ’                          -   decrement by one
      ⁶;                        -   concatenate a space with that   ...because -------.
        “         “       »     -   compressed list of strings:                       ↓
         £ṙƬs⁾`¬ụṂ              -     " is in the"  ← cannot compress a trailing space :(
                   ¢<ỴȦ8£l      -     "-comma club."
                           j    -   join that list of strings with the "number plus space"
                             ⁹  - right argument (names)
                              ż - zip with L
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>76</s> 74 bytes

```php
// data as associative array
$d=[Poorman=>-1234,John=>100000,Jamie=>0.05,Kylie=>1549001.10,Laura=>999999999.99,Russ=>1000000000,Karla=>1,Reid=>99.99,Mark=>999.99,Manson=>1000.01,Lonnie=>999999999999.00];
// code
foreach($d as$n=>$a)printf("$n is in the %d-comma club.
",log($a*$a,1e6));
```

Fortunately I don´t have to cast to int (as I would have to in C); PHP does that implicitly for `%d`.

Comment: Gee! Am I the first here to calculate instead of counting characters?

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 36 bytes

This takes in the amount as the first input, name as the second.

```
V+`   e {w0 x4 l /3-2|0}-¬mµ club
```

#### Explanation

```
V+`   e {w0 x4 l /3-2|0}-¬mµ club
V+                                   // Second input +
  `                                  // compressed string:
      e                              // " is in the " 
        {              }             // Insert here:
         w0                          //   The larger of 0 and the first input
            x4                       //   Rounded to the 4th decimal
               l                     //   Length
                        -¬mµ club    // "-comma club"
                                     // A closing backtick is auto-inserted at the end of the program
```

Japt uses the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) for string compression.

*Inspired by @Neil's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111745/61613).*

*Saved 7 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@x@mnaBwqFPhUIfCoQmpCtXlBgoVJgo5CvrGukY1BrW6h9bkHtqqkJxTmvT/v6EBCOgoeeVn5CkBAA)

Comment: I think you can just do `Vw0 x4 l /3-2|0` in the middle section, saving 6 bytes :-)

Comment: I think you can save a byte by taking input in the opposite order: ``V+`...{w0...``

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica (86 bytes)

The set-up (with names as strings, money as numbers):

```
n = {"John", "Jamie", "Kylie", "Laura", "Russ", "Karla", "Reid", "Mark", "Manson", "Lonnie", "Nelly"};
m = {100000, 0.05, 1549001.10, 999999999.99, 1000000000, 1, 99.99, 999.99, 1000.01, 999999999999.00, -123.45}
```

The attempt:

```
MapThread[#~~" is in the "~~ToString@Max[Floor@Log[10^3,#2],0]~~"-comma club."&,{n,m}]
```

All of Mathematica's string functions include "String" in the name, so I think logs are shorter. The `Max[...,0]` is to deal with the pesky negative numbers or negative infinity for people who own between -1 and 1 dollars. The log of a negative number includes imaginary stuff, but Mathematica helpfully ignores that when taking a `Floor`!

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 43 bytes

```
`j' is in the 'i|kVn3/XkqV'-comma club'&hDT
```

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=%60j%27+is+in+the+%27i%7CkVn3%2FXkqV%27-comma+club%27%26hDT&inputs=John%0A1000.05%0AJamie%0A0.05%0AKylie%0A1549001.10%0ALaura%0A999999999.99%0ARuss%0A1000000000%0AKarla%0A1%0AReid%0A99.99%0AMark%0A999.99%0AManson%0A1000.01%0ALonnie%0A999999999999.00%0ANelly%0A-123.45&version=19.8.0)

**Explanation**

```
`                   % Do...While loop
  j                 % Explicitly grab the next input as a string
  ' is in the the ' % Push this string literal to the stack
  i                 % Grab the next input as a number
  |                 % Compute the absolute value
  k                 % Round towards zero
  V                 % Convert to a string
  n3/Xk             % Divide the length of the string by 3 and round up
  q                 % Subtract one
  V                 % Convert to a string
  '-comma club'     % Push this string literal to the stack
  &h                % Horizontally concatenate the entire stack
  D                 % Display the resulting string
  T                 % Push TRUE to the stack, causing an infinite loop which automatically
                    % terminates when we run out of inputs
                    % Implicit end of do...while loop
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 32 bytes

```
Äï€g3/î<“-comma†Ú“«“€ˆ€†€€ “ì‚ø»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@45fD6R01r0o31D6@zedQwRzc5Pzc38VHDgsOzgLxDq4EEUPp0G5AACoLIpjUKQMHDQO6swzsO7f7/P1rd0AAE1HUU1A30DExBtKGpiaWBgaGeIVjUEgb0LC3BsgYwAOZBlEDlUFXpGRiiGACShejSNTQy1jMxVY/lilb3ys/IA4l5JeZmpoIY3pU5EIZPYmlRIogRVFpcDJZJLMqBCKRmpoBo38SibAidV5wPNsUnPy8PotsvNSenUj0WAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ä                                 # absolute value of input
 ï                                # convert to int
  €g                              # length of each
    3/                            # divided by 3
      î                           # round up
       <                          # decrement
        “-comma†Ú“«               # append string "-comma club" to each number
                   “€ˆ€†€€ “ì     # prepend string "is in the " to each number
                             ‚    # pair with second input
                              ø   # zip
                               »  # join by spaces and newlines
```

Answer (score 3):

## R, 68  bytes

The setup:

```
f <- c('John', 'Jamie', 'Kylie', 'Laura', 'Russ', 'Karla', 'Reid', 'Mark', 'Manson', 'Lonnie', 'Nelly')
a <- c(100000, 0.05, 1549001.10, 999999999.99, 986000000, 1, 99.99, 999.99, 1000.01, 999999999999.00, -123.45)
```

The solution:

```
cat(paste0(f, " is in the ",floor(log10(abs(a))/3)),"-comma club.\n"))
```

Take the base 10 log of the absolute value of the account, round down then print with the names.

I'm not sure if it could be smaller if `a` would be a character vector...

Comment: What about the case of Nelly, who has -123.45 dollars? That `log10` call will produce `NaN`s for negatives. Looks like `log10(abs(a))` would work.

Comment: Oops, you're right, the sample above didn't include Nelly. And I misread the specification... I understood negative value should be 0 comma club.

Comment: Instead of `abs(x)`, use `pmax(a,1)` - this will take anything less than 1 and make it 1, giving good results for negative numbers. And, instead of `floor(log10(...)/3)` you can use `log10(...)%/%3`. I think that gets it down to 66 bytes (and correct for negatives).

Comment: Also worth noting that a full 7 bytes of that are the `cat()` and `\n`... printing the vector with the strings in it to the console *might* be considered good enough (\*ahem\* like the Python answers).

Comment: This has an extra parenthesis after 3. It also outputs the -1 club for Jamie. Using pmax(a,1) fixes that.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript, 59 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @ETHproductions*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Cyoce*

```js
n=>m=>n+` is in the ${m>1?Math.log10(m)/3|0:0}-comma club.`
```

#### Demo

```js
f=n=>m=>n+` is in the ${m>1?Math.log10(m)/3|0:0}-comma club.`

console.log((f("John")(100000)))
console.log((f("Jamie")(0.05)))
console.log((f("Kylie")(1549001.10)))
console.log((f("Laura")(999999999.99)))
console.log((f("Russ")(986000000)))
console.log((f("Karla")(1)))
console.log((f("Reid")(99.99)))
console.log((f("Mark")(999.99)))
console.log((f("Manson")(1000.01)))
console.log((f("Lonnie")(999999999999.00)))
console.log((f("Nelly")(-123.45)))
```

Comment: Save a byte with `\`${}\`` and you can curry the function to `n=>m=>...` instead of `(n,m)=>...`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (<s>207 159 110 95</s> 86 bytes, thanks to @iwaseatenbyagrue)

A little bit of setup:

```
f = ['John', 'Jamie', 'Kylie', 'Laura', 'Russ', 'Karla', 'Reid', 'Mark', 'Manson', 'Lonnie', 'Nelly']
a = [100000, 0.05, 1549001.10, 999999999.99, 986000000, 1, 99.99, 999.99, 1000.01, 999999999999.00, -123.45]
```

My attempt:

```
['%s is in the %d-comma club.'%(p,-(-len(str(int(abs(v))))//3)-1) for p,v in zip(f,a)]
```

Results:

```
['John is in the 1-comma club.', 'Jamie is in the 0-comma club.', 'Kylie is in the 2-comma club.', 'Laura is in the 2-comma club.', 'Russ is in the 2-comma club.', 'Karla is in the 0-comma club.', 'Reid is in the 0-comma club.', 'Mark is in the 0-comma club.', 'Manson is in the 1-comma club.', 'Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.', 'Nelly is in the 0-comma club.']
```

Edit: converting everything to absolute values saved me 15 bytes.

Comment: Most importantly, this is a code snippet, Typically we only allow functions or full programs. As for golfing, You can remove many spaces. Try: `["%s is in the %d-comma club."%(p,v.count(','))for p,v in zip(f,a)]` Also, you must include a byte count.

Comment: You can do `print'\n'.join([your array])` and actually print output.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Is there a better tag for this question? I am unfamiliar with bytes as a parsimony metric, but would go for number of characters instead.

Comment: @not_a_robot Bytes and characters are essentially equivalent, and bytes are preferred.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Negatives (e.g. `-123.45`) are off by one (since you count the `-`). But why not take a list of numbers and save (have I misinterpreted?). You'd need to add import statements, and as it stands this is a snippet not a program or function (as the defaults are, and changing from them is discouraged unless there is good reason).

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanAllan. I'm currently trying to improve this so I don't have to count the imports. I realize that Python's `math.ceil` function likely adds quite a bit of overhead to my score.

Comment: You can save 9 bytes by replacing `(-len(str(abs(v)).split('.')[0])` with `len(str(int(float(v))))`.  In your test set, there are no negative numbers (in the examples, there is one). If you wanted to be completist, spend 5 bytes to do `len(str(abs(int(float(v)))))` - which then only saves you 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>89 86 84</s> 76 bytes

```python
for g,b in input():print g,'is in the',`~-len('%d'%abs(b))/3`+'-comma club.'
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NEoIgHMRfhYuDTkpgeaBH6OvQ1WlGLFMmBAf04KVXN8TUdjj9/rvLNn1bKRkPw0tpUIY54NK@pmv94NBoLlsLITcjbqsChtknEoX0ofeEHsuNnwfBdpdtYPRQdc3AQ3Q5gsOQpvCoKglDQPCoewgsYTW3FQAjnDhw6oUDJNlTjAkik@/MOs0sprMQpe5w64xZKpfaE9NitJPJU/Cny86hC9PvqWwl0qh5G8JT7qykdGPon9Dvi2shRG9vEYl3aJ/8WFk6tm68fwE)**

Full program that takes a list of pairs of names and bank balances - and prints the resulting strings. (Note the question states "friends array and amounts array, but this is the format used by the accepted answer, so I guess it's allowed!)

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 72 bytes

```
:%s;\v +\-=(\d+).*;\=' is in the '.(len(submatch(1))-1)/3.' comma club'
```

Somehow I should show that there's a trailing return, but unsure how.  This is just a basic regex answer, that I'm sure could be beaten by any regex language.  I would have used V, but I think that the substitute commands in V use `/` as a separator by default, and I couldn't figure out how to make it not complain about the divide.

Takes input as OP's table, and returns values as the table, but with the financial information replaced by " is in the X comma club"

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#TY5BDoIwEEX3PcVsDKBh7KgsKvECii5YsynQBGIpCQUTT49SIOHt/s/8lxmvOxtnHzhk4c3PykOA@zi7eVBbqA30lQIPfa2Mb4e8kX1R@RQEIQXHM3pQtE0jodBD7rFxvLeVAQfxCXaXTa1cwZFH7PHVS6ToIjgnJM4SOXTSlWIFhWDpYO3W5XwP2en5lliq6hKW3TR4yu695qUwtjWrATmxpDVmfkBswL/4pbT@unFIpzNeoh8)

Comment: I don't think the `\-=` adds anything. Also, if you remove the extra spaces in your input, and change the regex too `\v (\d*).*;` you could save 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 69 bytes

Setup our arrays:

```python
n = ['John', 'Jamie', 'Kylie', 'Laura', 'Russ', 'Karla', 'Reid', 'Mark', 'Manson', 'Lonnie']
a = [100000, 0.05, 1549001.10, 999999999.99, 1000000000, 1, 99.99, 999.99, 1000.01, 999999999999.00]
```

And our function can then be:

```python
f=lambda n,a:'%s is in %s comma club'%(n,min(3,(len(str(int(a)))/3)))
```

Giving us:

```python
>>> [f(x,y) for x,y in zip(n,a)]
['John is in 2 comma club', 'Jamie is in 0 comma club', 'Kylie is in 2 comma club', 'Laura is in 3 comma club', 'Russ is in 3 comma club', 'Karla is in 0 comma club', 'Reid is in 0 comma club', 'Mark is in 1 comma club', 'Manson is in 1 comma club', 'Lonnie is in 3 comma club']
```

If the array needs to be identical to that provided in the question, then the solution costs 76 bytes:

```python
f=lambda n,a:'%s is in %s comma club'%(n,min(3,(len(str(int(float(a))))/3)))
```

Comment: This does not take the arrays, but rather a single pair. Also, I don't think it caters for the negative number inputs as specified.

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, 82 bytes

```
$args[0]|%{$_[0]+" is in the "+(('{0:N}'-f$_[1]-split',').Count-1)+"-comma club."}
```

Assuming a 2D-array input of

`cc.ps1 @(@("John",100000),@("Jamie",0.05),@("Kylie",1549001.10),@("Laura",999999999.99),@("Russ",986000000),@("Karla",1),@("Reid",99.99),@("Mark",999.99),@("Manson",1000.01),@("Lonnie",999999999999.00),@("Nelly",-123.45))`

The output is

`John is in the 1-comma club.
Jamie is in the 0-comma club.
Kylie is in the 2-comma club.
Laura is in the 2-comma club.
Russ is in the 2-comma club.
Karla is in the 0-comma club.
Reid is in the 0-comma club.
Mark is in the 0-comma club.
Manson is in the 1-comma club.
Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.
Nelly is in the 0-comma club.`

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 71 bytes

```
n#a=n++" is in the "++(show.truncate.logBase 1e3.abs$a)++"-comma club."
```

Defines an operator '#' that provides the correct answer.  E.g.:

```
*Main> "John"#100000
"John is in the 1-comma club."
```

Unfortunately, Haskell doesn't have a compact `log10` function like many other languages, but it does have a useful `logBase` function, which means we don't need to divide our answer by 3.  Unfortunately, `logBase 1000 0.05` is a negative number, so we need to use the longer `truncate` rather than `floor` to round it.

Full program including test cases:

```
(#) :: (RealFrac n, Floating n) => [Char] -> n -> [Char]
n#a=n++" is in the "++(show.truncate.logBase 1e3.abs$a)++"-comma club."

testCases = [
 ("John",      100000),
 ("Jamie",     0.05),
 ("Kylie",     1549001.10),
 ("Laura",     999999999.99),
 ("Russ",      986000000),
 ("Karla",     1),
 ("Reid",      99.99),
 ("Mark",      999.99),
 ("Manson",    1000.01),
 ("Lonnie",    999999999999.00),
 ("Nelly",     -123.45)]

main = putStrLn $ unlines $ map (uncurry (#)) testCases
```

Gives the following results:

```
John is in the 1-comma club.
Jamie is in the 0-comma club.
Kylie is in the 2-comma club.
Laura is in the 2-comma club.
Russ is in the 2-comma club.
Karla is in the 0-comma club.
Reid is in the 0-comma club.
Mark is in the 0-comma club.
Manson is in the 1-comma club.
Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.
Nelly is in the 0-comma club.
```

Answer (score 1):

### K, 66 bytes

```
    /n is names and a is amounts
    n
    ("John";"Jamie";"Kylie";"Laura";"Russ";"Karla";"Reid";"Mark";"Manson";"Lonnie")
    a
    ("100000";"0.05";"1549001.10";"999999999.99";"1000000000";,"1";"99.99";"999.99";"1000.01";"999999999999.00")
    /the function
    {x," is in the ",($(#.q.cut[3;*"."\:y])-1)," comma club"}./:+(n;a)
    /output
    ("John is in the 1 comma club";"Jamie is in the 0 comma club";"Kylie is in the 2 comma club";"Laura is in the 2 comma club";"Russ is in the 3 comma club";"Karla is in the 0 comma club";"Reid is in the 0 comma club";"Mark is in the 0 comma club";"Manson is in the 1 comma club";"Lonnie is in the 3 comma club")
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 125 bytes

```
(p,n)=>{for(int x=0;x<p.Length;x++)Console.Write(p[x]+" is in the "+(n[x]<1e3?0:n[x]<1e6?1:n[x]<1e9?2:3)+"-comma club.\n");};
```

Anonymous function which prints the result in the the OP's format.

Full program with test cases:

```
using System;

class CommaClub
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action<string[], double[]> f =
        (p,n)=>{for(int x=0;x<p.Length;x++)Console.Write(p[x]+" is in the "+(n[x]<1e3?0:n[x]<1e6?1:n[x]<1e9?2:3)+"-comma club.\n");};
        
        // test cases:
        string[] personArr = new[] {"John", "Jamie", "Kylie", "Laura", "Russ", "Karla", "Reid", "Mark", "Manson", "Lonnie", "Nelly"};
        double[] amountArr = new[] {100000, 0.05, 1549001.10, 999999999.99, 1000000000, 1, 99.99, 999.99, 1000.01, 999999999999.00, -123.45};
        f(personArr, amountArr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 87 bytes

```python
for n,a in input():print n+' is in the %dd-comma club.'%'{:20,.2f}'.format(a).count(',')
```

Slightly older (90 bytes):

```python
for n,a in input():print n+' is in the '+`'{:20,.2f}'.format(a).count(',')`+'-comma club.'
```

Takes input as a list of tuples (name, amount).

I'm doing this on my phone at school so I'll test it later.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, <s>107</s> 95 bytes

```
for @f {printf "%s is in the %d-comma club.\n",@f[$++],(abs(@a[$++].split(".")[0]).chars-1)/3;}
```

Not my proudest work, give me a heads up if ive forgotten any golfing techniques.
EDIT: -12 bytes thanks to @Ven

Comment: why parens around `^@f.elems`? btw you don't need that `.elems`, `for ^@f` works. You don't need to name your `$x`, use `$_` instead. And don't use printf, use `"{"interpolation"}"`.

Comment: I don't even understand why you need that. Why not go for `for @f`? You can use `$++` as an index to go along with it (and index into `@a`).

Comment: ill edit as soon as im on the pc :)

Comment: @Ven thanks for the heads up about the $++. Saves me alot of trouble in my "real" programs. Just picked up Perl 6.

Comment: Are you sure interpolations don't save bytes?

Comment: That `@f[$++]` can be `$_`, as said in my first comment. However you probably want to `for @a` so you can write `abs(.split…)` (and keep `@f[$++]`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](https://www.swift.org), <s>166</s> <s>158</s> 145 bytes

```swift
var c="comma club",i=0
f.map{k,v in var a=abs(v);print(k,(1000..<1000000~=a ?1:1000000..<1000000000~=a ?2:1000000000..<1000000000000~=a ?3:0),c)}
```

And here is the dictionary:

```swift
var f = [
    "John": 100000, "Jamie": 0.05, "Kylie" : 1549001.10,
    "Laura": 999999999.99,"Russ":1000000000,"Karla": 1,
    "Reid": 99.99,"Mark": 999.99, "Manson": 1000.01,
    "Lonnie": 999999999999.00, "Nelly": -123.45
]
```

**[Try it here!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ad3583dd73eb75289a5494)**

Answer (score 1):

### dc, <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
[P[ is in the ]Pd*vdZrX-1-3/n[-comma club.]pstz0<g]sglgx
```

This takes input from the stack, which should be pre-loaded with the first name at top of stack, the first number, the second name, second number, etc.

Here is an example of loading the stack and running the macro, g:

```
#!/usr/bin/dc
_123.45         [Nelly]
999999999999.00 [Lonnie]
1000.01         [Manson]
999.99          [Mark]
99.99           [Reid]
1               [Karla]
986000000       [Russ]
999999999.99    [Laura]
1549001.10      [Kylie]
0.05            [Jamie]
100000          [John]
[P[ is in the ]Pd*v1/Z1-3/n[-comma club.]pstz0<g]sglgx
```

which produces the usual output,

```
John is in the 1-comma club.
Jamie is in the 0-comma club.
Kylie is in the 2-comma club.
Laura is in the 2-comma club.
Russ is in the 2-comma club.
Karla is in the 0-comma club.
Reid is in the 0-comma club.
Mark is in the 0-comma club.
Manson is in the 1-comma club.
Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.
Nelly is in the 0-comma club.
```

Here's an exegesis of the code:

```
[P[ is in the ]Pd*v1/Z-1-3/n[-comma club.]pstz0<g]sglgx

[                    # begin macro string
P                    # print and pop person name
[ is in the ]P       # print and pop ' is in the '
# Get absolute value of number by squaring and square root
d*v                  # d=dup, *=multiply, v=root
1/                   # 1/ truncates to integer since scale is 0
Z                    # Z=number length
1-3/n                # n=print and pop (#digits - 1)//3
[-comma club.]p      # print '-comma club.' and newline
st                   # pop '-comma club.' off stack into register t
z0<g                 # Do macro g if 0 is less than z=stack height
]                    # end macro string
sg                   # Save macro g
lgx                  # Load g and do its initial execution
```

Note, in edit 1 I replaced `dZrX-` (d=dup, Z=number length, r=swap, X=fraction, -=subtract) with `1/Z` (divide number by 1, which with default scale of zero truncates to integer; then Z=number length), saving two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 55 bytes

```javascript
n=>m=>n+` is in the ${Math.log10(m*m)/6|0}-comma club.`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJLT@MwFEb3/hV3MRL2QF07tIhQpaxgwVNCs@Ih1QRDPONHZadQBPz2ThwnNNzdPbnfsR37r3gVofRqWY9eDzels6GG0hkjoNjYYm6Kud1dgAqgLNSVhF8fl6KuqHYvnGHz25DxwSf7GqVIqVePdLGZIZREz15J@xSggAU6c5WFtjiLhc6EUbIFjLIpOn/XXcunk5wxTjlDF2LlRQvzvmieo5tVCMmVHx6wpDsXXqdRjm6keuq@t/OXwv/r@w7Y4Gy/Gco4unDWpvXzQdFGfCW1fm/DI57t08kU3UrveCKdL5JsuMC1lWmiCcXdNX22PX1s9@HbsM1MYHDYyP68uaEnZhuUDX9kS37atuEfwh5XXqbd9c5WEmk20Ea4oLVXBhMENCy1qvHOvd2J3bPzJ6KssFZWQjGHDwSQ7vzOCiP3oBShemguPg502THsjgk1Yonxeg8UiTkFx7AUPshT7USN1wSOYE1mnc1pGV8abl8XjmKCo5g0E19ktvkP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 29 bytes

```
¹ð«E⟨b?6Ḃ«⁰²∆τ6ḭS‹`ḊṄa ⟇¦.`Wṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCucOwwqtF4p+oYj824biCwqvigbDCsuKIhs+ENuG4rVPigLlg4biK4bmEYSDin4fCpi5gV+G5hSIsIiIsIlJ1c3Ncbjk4NjAwMDAwMCJd)

### Explained

```
¹ð«E⟨b?6Ḃ«⁰²∆τ6ḭS‹`ḊṄa ⟇¦.`Wṅ
¹ð                             # Get first input and push space
  «E⟨b?6Ḃ«                     # Push compressed string "is in the "
          ⁰²                   # Get second input and square it
            ∆τ                 # Log10 it
              6ḭ               # Floor divide by 6
                S              # Stringify
                 ‹             # Push a hyphen
                  `ḊṄa ⟇¦.`    # Push string "comma club"
                           Wṅ  # Join stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8 <s>154</s> 141 bytes

```
m.keySet().stream().map(k->k+" is in the "+(((""+Math.abs(m.get(k).longValue()))).length()-1)/3+"-comma club.").forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

### Ungolfed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Number> m = new LinkedHashMap<String, Number>(){{
        put("John", 100000);
        put("Jamie", 0.05);
        put("Kylie", 1549001.10);
        put("Laura", 999999999.99);
        put("Russ", 1000000000);
        put("Karla", 1);
        put("Reid", 99.99);
        put("Mark", 999.99);
        put("Manson", 1000.01);
        put("Lonnie", 999999999999.00);
        put("Nelly", -123.45);
    }};
    m.keySet().stream().map(k->k+" is in the "+(((""+Math.abs(m.get(k).longValue()))).length()-1)/3+"-comma club.").forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `String.valueOf` and use `(((""+Math.abs(m.get(k).longValue())).length()-1)/3)` instead.

Comment: And you can also remove the parenthesis around `k->`.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 108 bytes

```
(def f ["John", "Jamie", "Kylie", "Laura", "Russ", "Karla", "Reid", "Mark", "Manson", "Lonnie", "Nelly"])
(def a ["100000", "0.05", "1549001.10", "999999999.99", "986000000", "1", "99.99", "999.99", "1000.01", "999999999999.00", "-123.45"])

(map #(str %" is in the "(quot(-(count(nth(partition-by #{\.}(drop-while #{\-}%2))0))1)3)"-comma club.")f a)
```

Not sure if operating on floats would be shorted than on sequences of characters. Not sure if non-function answer is fine which returns a sequence of answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol, 118 bytes

```
d: charset"0123456789"forskip s 2[c: 0 parse s/2[opt"-"any[3 d and d(++ c)]]print[s/1"is in the"join c"-comma club."]]
```

Ungolfed with array declaration:

```
s: [
    {John} {100000}
    {Jamie} {0.05}
    {Kylie} {1549001.10}
    {Laura} {999999999.99}
    {Russ} {986000000}
    {Karla} {1}
    {Reid} {99.99}
    {Mark} {999.99}
    {Manson} {1000.01}
    {Lonnie} {999999999999.00}
    {Nelly} {-123.45}
    {Baz} {1.12345678}     ;; added extra Baz test case
]

d: charset "0123456789"
forskip s 2 [
    c: 0
    parse s/2 [
        opt "-"
        any [3 d and d (++ c)]
    ]
    print [s/1 "is in the" join c "-comma club."]
]
```

Output:

```
John is in the 1-comma club.
Jamie is in the 0-comma club.
Kylie is in the 2-comma club.
Laura is in the 2-comma club.
Russ is in the 2-comma club.
Karla is in the 0-comma club.
Reid is in the 0-comma club.
Mark is in the 0-comma club.
Manson is in the 1-comma club.
Lonnie is in the 3-comma club.
Nelly is in the 0-comma club.
Baz is in the 0-comma club.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 52 bytes

```
[ sq log10 6 /i [I ${} is in the ${}-comma club.I] ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZFBTsMwEEXFNqcYVWxjbEirBg6AQksXIFZRFsa4xKpjF9sRqqKchE02cAeOAqchqZM29C9sWc9_xn_88bWmzGnT_J69Pz0mq9troNZqZmHDjeISCury_YLWpWJOaGVBKMfNVkvqOAgNN0FQBdCqgsmdztUE9iK4E9QHRAvBPcMIT49gsZMDINMoxpggMvItaWmox_EgFMfHCw-ltX3PeD7DJ20X1MjeTkYeLl4Gz_9q99RsDuQUKat9vC4cwqOCS61UnyIeCY2fsuJS7nztkFxeoagbQv1ZunU4_4lSsG8g9WubfQYXAtIEzqsaRDdvcDnvTiHTRUGByfIZJRlk3vudgpKQQQu32nL_gyGnLPe8afz-Bw)

Port of @MatthewJensen's [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246158/97916).

Comment: [doesn't work for me...](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVBBTsMwEBTXvGIV9Rpjl6Rq4AEotPQA4hTlsASnserYwXYOBfESLrnAJ3gJvIakThBzsLWzM-OR3z8rLJ02_c_Z4uE-211fwoEbxSU06OrTQapOlU5oZUEox02rJToOe664QSlecNppuAqC8EbXKoQTGB0xUNgI7jlKaBKEm6OcCZbEKaWMsEG3xc6gp9MZJE2D8K6zdspM1ys6xW7QyEnOBg0XT7PGu27RHP6YmVJW-3pjOUIH41YrNbVJ_4GMT-y4lEefEbHlBYmTj85V0fo7zsE-g9R7RmEF5wLyDBavbyDGPwJX83GKSt00CKXsHklWQOG9XzkoCQUMy1ZbDktgDBqFbSuPXtH3_v4F) could you get a working ATO/TIO link?

Comment: @Steffan I had no idea about ATO. It uses a later build than TIO so `[I` works. The problem is that `mnapply` is bugged in that build. Try [this](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZFBTsMwEEXFNqcYVWxjbEirBg6AQksXIFZRFsa4xKpjF9sRqqKchE02cAeOAqchqZM29C9sWc9_xn_88bWmzGnT_J69Pz0mq9troNZqZmHDjeISCury_YLWpWJOaGVBKMfNVkvqOAgNN0FQBdCqgsmdztUE9iK4E9QHRAvBPcMIT49gsZMDINMoxpggMvItaWmox_EgFMfHCw-ltX3PeD7DJ20X1MjeTkYeLl4Gz_9q99RsDuQUKat9vC4cwqOCS61UnyIeCY2fsuJS7nztkFxeoagbQv1ZunU4_4lSsG8g9WubfQYXAtIEzqsaRDdvcDnvTiHTRUGByfIZJRlk3vudgpKQQQu32nL_gyGnLPe8afz-Bw).